# google geocoding service combined with openlayers - not working

Tags: geocoding, openlayers-2, google-maps-api, google

I'm trying to combine google's [geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) with openlayers. So when a user types an address and hits enter, map zooms there and renders a simple point. I edited my code according to the previous link. Does not work. I'm using a vector layer as basic (comes from Geoserver/PostGIS), a google's layer as second basic. I also added a simple vector layer to render the adrress's point. Do  I have to bind google's layer and geocoding service somehow?

Here is my code. 
Can you spot what's wrong?

```
var geocoder;
function codeAddress() 
{alert ('inside function');//works
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;    

//tell to user, he did not type anything
if (address==""){document.getElementById("geocodMsgG").innerHTML = "You gave no input";}
else{

alert(address);//works

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) 
  {alert(status);//not work

   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {     
     alert('inside 2 function');//not work
     alert(results[0].geometry.location);//not work
     //create a geometry point
     pointgc = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(results[0].geometry.location);

     //create a feature point
     feature_point_gc = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pointgc);

       //lfl contains bounds that i set earlier in my code
       if (lfl.containsLonLat(results[0].geometry.location)){
       //render the point on the layer named geoco
       geoco.addFeatures([feature_point_gc]);
       geoco.refresh({force:true});
       //zoom there
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);   
      }
      //if point is not inside the bounds (lfl) then dont add - print msg to user
      else{document.getElementById("geocodMsgG").innerHTML = "out of bounds";}
  } 

  //refers to the second if(geocoding's status)
  else {document.getElementById("geocodMsgG").innerHTML = "error";}    

});//geocode 
}//major else (if address empty or not)
}//function
```

Comment: This is not an OpenLayers question, suggest you remove tag.  Also, try to simplify your code and/or create a separate test page that ONLY geocodes, nothing else.  Have it geocode a static address or an input field and output to console w/o a map.  Good luck.

Comment: @ Vadim I thought it is an OpenLayers question, because I'm trying to render the output of geocoding API on an OpenLayers map. Anyway, create a test page is not a bad idea, thanks

Comment: This'll be an OL question when it becomes "hey, I can get the results back from google and output to console/div/alert but can't plot them on OL map".  However, be aware that Google Maps TOS require you to plot google data on a google map.

Comment: Given Google's TOS restriction, MapQuest's geocoding api might be an alternative.

Comment: Well if google require a google map, just add the google layers as base layer and set it active when the search runs OK. SO you can use it with OpenLayers too.

Comment: @cavila@Cyrus@Vadim Thanks for the ansers. I think the problems are the Google TOS restriction and also another thing I just notided : the points on openlayers vector layers are like (lon, lat) BUT the points came from Google geocoding are like (lat,lon). I'm copying from Googles page : "location contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value. Note that we return this location as a LatLng object, not as a formatted string" . Anyway, I'm still looking for a solution...

Comment: I think I just found something that fits my needs. Check the source code of this, [link](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/openls.html). They use proxy to get the geocoding working, right? Before I set a proxy, I want to ask you guys, do you think, I will be able to use the `var foundPosition` to render a simple point on an OpenLayer's vector layer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use Openlayers 3 you can make use of an extension that I've written, some instructions at: https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol3-geocoder. A screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like geocoder variable was not initialized. it is an object instance, not a static class, or function.

```
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

There should be a javascript error on page.